# LibCrypt what is the use of the `ctx` parameter on BN_div?

Tags: c, openssl, division, bignum, libcrypto

In my attempt to implement the [Burmester-Desmedt](https://en.bmstu.wiki/Burmester-Desmedt_(protocol)) key agreement using pure C I need to divide 2 public keys thus I thought the [`BN_div`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/BN_div.html) should do the job.

```
int BN_div(BIGNUM *dv, BIGNUM *rem, const BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *d,BN_CTX *ctx);
```

But when I read the documentation:

> divides a by d and places the result in dv and the remainder in rem (dv=a/d, rem=a%d). Either of dv and rem may be NULL, in which case the respective value is not returned. The result is rounded towards zero; thus if a is negative, the remainder will be zero or negative. For division by powers of 2, use BN_rshift(3).

I cannot understand what the parameter `ctx` is used for, so far what I understood that does is:

```
rem=a%d
dv=a/d
```

The `ctx` in this operation what is used for is parameter used for some sort of recursion and should be set as `NULL` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For all functions, ctx is a previously allocated BN_CTX used for temporary variables; see BN_CTX_new.

so you have to do

```
BN_CTX *ctx = BN_CTX_new();
BIGNUM dv;
BIGNUM rem;
BIGNUM a = ...;
BIGNUM d = ...;

if (!BN_div(&dv, &rem, &a, &d, ctx))
  ...error case
else
  ...ok case
```

if you have other `BN_xx` to call you can reuse the same *ctx*, this is the goal

Answer (score 2):

Verbatim from the [docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/BN_CTX_new.html):

> A BN_CTX is a structure that holds BIGNUM temporary variables used by library functions. Since dynamic memory allocation to create BIGNUMs is rather expensive when used in conjunction with repeated subroutine calls, the BN_CTX structure is used.

Use  `BN_CTX_new()` to create a context. Call `BN_CTX_free()` when done.